# React-Native: facebook login without Expo

Tags: react-native

Trying to build facebook login. But having some issue in the code. at the "await logInWithReadPermissionAsync" part all examples about Expo. For example. "Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync" but I am not using Expo, so how can I fix that part...?

I tried this without Expo `Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync`, but it didn't run properly. It says promise rejection.

```
  async facebookLogin (){
const {type, token} = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionAsync(
  'My ID',
  {permission:['public_profile']}
);

if(type === 'success'){
  const credentials = f.auth().FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
  f.auth.signInWithCredential(credential).catch((error) => {
    console.log('error...', error);
  })
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't using expo, use [rn facebook sdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk). Then you can access the method as :

```
import { LoginManager } from "react-native-fbsdk";

// Attempt a login using the Facebook login dialog asking for default permissions.
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"]).then(
  // ... refer to docs    
);
```